# How to use my own middleware with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a `authorize` middleware to allow the authorized user to go next, I use it like this:

```
router.post('/new-session-card', authorize(Role.Admin), newSessionCard);
```

So if the user is authorized he/she will go to `newSessionCard` function right ?

Now I want to use it with socket.io:

```
io.use(authorize(Role.Admin), () => {
        console.log('here')
});
```

The issue is the console log never reaches although the user is authorized .

Is there anyway to use my own middleware with socket,io ?

Comment: https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/

Comment: I saw that but how o use it ?

Comment: @SaraRee These will help you for socket server - 1. https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/#compatibility-with-express-middleware; 2. https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/#compatibility-with-express-middleware;
And this for socket client - https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/#compatibility-with-express-middleware

Answer (score 1):

You can use function `bind` method in `io.use()` like this

In your case you can use it like

```js
let Role = {
  Admin: "superuser"
};

function authorize(socket, next) {
   console.log("Role", this.role);
   next();
}

io.use(authorize.bind({role: Role.Admin}), () => {
        console.log('here')
});
```